# Ranges (intervals) request in Cassandra DB - CQL

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql, cql3

Excuse, if it is a duplicate, I've found a few questions about times ranges here, but my case seems a little bit different and not yet discussed.

I would like to store quite big chunks (bins) of data (blobs - 2-4Mb, this is the “black-box data”, I can't change its layout) to access with interval keys:

```
...
primary key ( bin_id int, from_item_id int, to_item_id int ) 
...
```

with ability to select with items ranges, like in this pseudo-code to select all chunks that contains interval of items *[110, 200]*:

```
select chunk from tb1 where chunk_id = 100500 and from_item_id >= 110 and to_item_id <= 200;
```

Attempt to run such a query directly ended with error:

```
code=2200 [Invalid query] message="PRIMARY KEY column "to_item_id" cannot be restricted (preceding column "from_item_id" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)"
```

Currently only solution I've found is to implement additional table (tb_map) with reverse mapping from item_id to bin_id and use select to make a query looks something like this:

```
...
– in tb_map
primary key (dummy_id, item_id)
...
select bin_id from tb_map where dummy_id = SOME_MAGIK and item_id >= 110 and item_id <= 200;
```

And then use bin_id to retrieve chunks from tb1 with EQ or IN operator like here:

```
select * from tb1 where bin_id in (...);
```

But I can't use this model due insert performance issues (application should avoid many inserts to additional table and should avoid maintaining additional data structures, but should be "as simple as nail").

Is it any simple solution to stay within one table (or several simple tables)? I'm stuck with no ideas how to model such behaviour in C* (may be slices should be used?), could local  C* gurus provide any hints?

I'm using CQL 3.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28565470/cassandra-primary-key-column-cannot-be-restricted

Answer (score 0):

From [CQL3 reference](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#selectWhere):

> Moreover, for a given partition key, the clustering columns induce an ordering of rows and relations on them is restricted to the relations that allow to select a contiguous (for the ordering) set of rows.

In your case the query doesn't select a contiguous set of rows, so Cassandra refuses to process it.